# RShiny not loading due to input to json

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am probably going to kick myself when I find out what the reason is for the error but I can't work it out.

I am trying to make an RShiny plot on sales from May to September with the option to subcategorise based on online sources for the sales of products. Even though I have done one previously and used it as a template I keep getting the persistent error that:

*"Input to asJSON(keep_vec_names=TRUE) is a named vector. In a future version of jsonlite, this option will not be supported, and named vectors will be translated into arrays instead of objects. If you want JSON object output, please use a named list instead. See ?toJSON."*

The graph the loads with this error but without text or a graph just *"Error: [object Object]"*

I am completely stumped and I finish working there tomorrow so if anyone has some pointers I would be incredibly grateful. Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

#Data preparation 

all_sales_may_september_filtered <- read_csv("all_sales_may_september_filtered.csv")

# Define UI

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Summer Sales 2023"),
  sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
  selectInput("source", "Select Source:",
              choices = c("All Sources", unique(all_sales_may_september_filtered$source))),
  uiOutput("sku_selection") # Dynamic UI for SKU Drop Down Selection
),
# Modify the UI
mainPanel(
  plotlyOutput("sales_plot"),
  verbatimTextOutput("sales_info") # Change to verbatimTextOutput
    )
  )
)


# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
# Create a dynamic UI for the SKU drop-down menu based on selected "default_source"
  output$sku_selection <- renderUI({
   if (input$source == "All Sources") {
  source_filtered <- all_sales_may_september_filtered
} else {
  source_filtered <- all_sales_may_september_filtered %>% 
    filter(source == input$source)
}
selectInput("sku", "Select SKU:", choices = unique(source_filtered$sku))
 })

 output$sales_plot <- renderPlotly({
filtered_sales <- all_sales_may_september_filtered %>% 
  filter(default_source == input$source | input$source == "All Sources",
         sku == input$sku) %>% 
  group_by(recieved_date) %>% 
  summarise(daily_sales = sum(order_item_quantity))


   plot_ly(filtered_sales, x = ~recieved_date, y = ~daily_sales, type = "scatter", mode = "lines",
        line = list(color = "goldenrod")) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = lis`your text`t(title = "Order Date"),
         yaxis = list(title = "Total Sold"),
         title = "Summer Sales of 2023")
```

})

```
   # Modify the renderUI for sales_info
 output$sales_info <- renderPrint({
filtered_sales <- all_sales_may_september_filtered %>% 
  filter(default_source == input$source | input$source == "All Sources",
         sku == input$sku) %>% 
  summarise(daily_sales = sum(order_item_quantity),
            default_source = unique(default_source))

# Create a character vector with the information
output_text <- paste("Daily Sales:", filtered_sales$daily_sales, "\nDefault Source:",       filtered_sales$default_source)

   # Return the character vector
   return(output_text)
```

})

```
  # Run the app`your text`
 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have tried to edit the renderUI several time and discussed help with ChatGPT but nothing has been fruitful.

I tried also taking out plotly to not over complicate things but it is still not fruitful.

Comment: It's hard to help when your code is not reproducible. Do you have a sample of `all_sales_may_september_filtered.csv`?

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned in my comment, it's hard to help without a reproducible dataset. However, that error message seems to be `plotly` trying to parse an object that is not a dataframe.

In this case whenever you want to make a dynamic set of options you should make it a `reactive` object that then you can evaluate inside your `selectInput` like this. See if this helps (replace your `output$sku_selection` with this):

```r
# Create a dynamic UI for the SKU drop-down menu based on selected "default_source"
sku_selection <- reactive({
    if (input$source == "All Sources") {
      all_sales_may_september_filtered
    } else {
      all_sales_may_september_filtered %>% 
        filter(carb == input$source)
    }
  })
  
  output$sku_selection <- renderUI({
    
    selectInput("sku", "Select SKU:", choices = unique(sku_selection()$sku))
  })
```